# How would I make a page only accessable if a mysql varible is '1'?

Tags: php

So, at the moment, I am working on a mod panel for a forum. There is a varible in the database called 'moderator'. The default is 0, but I would like to be able to set it to '1', and then people would have access to a page. I was currently looking at something like the below:

```
<?php 
include('config.php');
    if(isset($_SESSION['moderator']) and $_SESSION['moderator']) {
    } else {
    header("location:noaccess.php");
}
?>
```

However, it doesn't work as I cannot figure out a way of saying if it is 1, then allow access. This is the contense of the config.php. '*' = Removed info

```
<?php
/******************************************************
------------------Required Configuration---------------
Please edit the following variables so the forum can
work correctly.
******************************************************/

//We log to the DataBase
mysql_connect('*', '*', '*');
mysql_select_db('forum_database');

//Username of the Administrator
$admin='The_Darthonian'; // For admin forum features

/******************************************************
-----------------Optional Configuration----------------
******************************************************/

//Forum Home Page
$url_home = 'index.php';

//Design Name
$design = 'default';


/******************************************************
----------------------Initialization-------------------
******************************************************/
include('init.php');
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not test the presence of a file?

Comment: `if(condition == 1){...} else{...}` is the basic logic. Read up on sessions on php.net http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flip your logic...

```
<?php 
include 'config.php';

if(empty($_SESSION['moderator'])) {
    // $_SESSION['moderator'] is not set or 0
    header("Location:noaccess.php");
    exit;
}

// $_SESSION['moderator'] is set and something other than 0,
// the following page is moderator only...
```